# Mapping issue on Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, mapping, jhipster

I am in the middle of developing a JHipster project and I've come to a halt due to what I believe to be mapping issues

My Database has several tables, but the two that affect me here are Study and Publication, where they have a Many to Many relationship.

I need to retrieve the collection of Publications where a study can be published, hence Study is the owner of the relationship, but for some reason, Hibernate don't recognise the attributes I map the relation with.

All of this started trying to solve a lazy connection issue, yes I have been through most posts relating this and I have tried everything that made sense to me.

Here the code of Study:

```
@Audited
@Entity
@Table(name = "Study")
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
@Document(indexName = "study")
public class Study implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "num_sites")
    private Integer numSites;

    @Column(name = "ref")
    private String ref;

    @Column(name = "study_type")
    private String studyType;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
    @JoinTable(name = "Pub_Study",
               joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="studies_id", referencedColumnName="id"),
               inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="publications_id", referencedColumnName="id"))
    public static Set<Publication> publications = new HashSet<>();

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "study")
    @JsonIgnore
    @Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
    private Set<SiteData> siteDatas = new HashSet<>();

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Integer getNumSites() {
        return numSites;
    }

    public void setNumSites(Integer numSites) {
        this.numSites = numSites;
    }

    public String getRef() {
        return ref;
    }

    public void setRef(String ref) {
        this.ref = ref;
    }

    public String getStudyType() {
        return studyType;
    }

    public void setStudyType(String studyType) {
        this.studyType = studyType;
    }

    public static Set<Publication> getPublicationss() {
        return publications;
    }

    public void setPublicationss(Set<Publication> publications) {
        this.publications = publications;
    }

    public Set<SiteData> getSiteDatas() {
        return siteDatas;
    }

    public void setSiteDatas(Set<SiteData> siteDatas) {
        this.siteDatas = siteDatas;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) {
            return true;
        }
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) {
            return false;
        }
        Study study = (Study) o;
        if(study.id == null || id == null) {
            return false;
        }
        return Objects.equals(id, study.id);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hashCode(id);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Study{" +
            "id=" + id +
            ", numSites='" + numSites + "'" +
            ", ref='" + ref + "'" +
            ", studyType='" + studyType + "'" +
            '}';
    }
```

Here the code of Publication:

```
@Audited
@Entity
@Table(name = "Publication")
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
@Document(indexName = "publication")
public class Publication implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "authors")
    private String authors;

    @Column(name = "first_author")
    private String firstAuthor;

    @Column(name = "journal")
    private String journal;

    @Column(name = "pubMedId")
    private Integer pubMedId;

    @Column(name = "title")
    private String title;

    @Column(name = "year_publish")
    private Integer yearPublish;

    @Version
    Integer version;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JsonIgnore
    @Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
    private Set<Study> studies = new HashSet<>();

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getAuthors() {
        return authors;
    }

    public void setAuthors(String authors) {
        this.authors = authors;
    }

    public String getFirstAuthor() {
        return firstAuthor;
    }

    public void setFirstAuthor(String firstAuthor) {
        this.firstAuthor = firstAuthor;
    }

    public String getJournal() {
        return journal;
    }

    public void setJournal(String journal) {
        this.journal = journal;
    }

    public Integer getPubMedId() {
        return pubMedId;
    }

    public void setPubMedId(Integer pubMedId) {
        this.pubMedId = pubMedId;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public Integer getYearPublish() {
        return yearPublish;
    }

    public void setYearPublish(Integer yearPublish) {
        this.yearPublish = yearPublish;
    }

    public Set<Study> getStudies() {
        return studies;
    }

    public void setStudies(Set<Study> studys) {
        this.studies = studys;
    }

    public Integer getVersion(){
        return version;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) {
            return true;
        }
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) {
            return false;
        }
        Publication publication = (Publication) o;
        if(publication.id == null || id == null) {
            return false;
        }
        return Objects.equals(id, publication.id);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hashCode(id);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Publication{" +
            "id=" + id +
            ", authors='" + authors + "'" +
            ", firstAuthor='" + firstAuthor + "'" +
            ", journal='" + journal + "'" +
            ", pubMedId='" + pubMedId + "'" +
            ", title='" + title + "'" +
            ", yearPublish='" + yearPublish + "'" +
            '}';
    }
}
```

Here the Implementation of the query from the Repository package:

```
public class SiteDataRepositoryImpl implements SiteDataRepositoryCustom{

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;

    @Override
    public List <SiteDataViewDTO> searchSiteDataByFilter(List<Filter> listFilters) {
        TypedQuery<SiteData> query = buildQuery(listFilters);
        Hibernate.initialize(Study.publications);
        int count=0;
        for (Filter filter: listFilters){
            if("country".equals(filter.getName()))
                query.setParameter(filter.getName(), filter.getQuery());
            else if("category".equals(filter.getName()))
                query.setParameter(filter.getName(), filter.getQuery());
            else if("studyRef".equals(filter.getName()))
                query.setParameter(filter.getName(), filter.getQuery());
            else if("studyType".equals(filter.getName()))
                query.setParameter(filter.getName(), filter.getQuery());
            else if("pubMedId".equals(filter.getName()))
                query.setParameter(filter.getName(), Integer.valueOf(filter.getQuery()));
            count++;
        }

        List<SiteData> siteDataList = query.getResultList();

        List<SiteDataViewDTO> siteDataViewDTOList=new ArrayList<SiteDataViewDTO>();

        //temp variables
        List<String>tempListTreatments = new ArrayList<String>();
        List<String>tempListTitles = new ArrayList<String>();
        List<Integer>tempListIdMed = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        //filling SiteDataViewDTO list
        siteDataList.stream().forEach(sd->{
             SiteDataViewDTO temp = new SiteDataViewDTO();
             temp.setTypeStudy(sd.getTypeStudy() + "id SiteData: " + sd.getId());
             temp.setRef(sd.getStudy().getRef());
             temp.setCategory(sd.getCategory().getName());
             temp.setUpper95CI(sd.getUpper95CI());
             temp.setYearStart(sd.getYearStart());
             temp.setYearEnd(sd.getYearEnd());
             Set<Publication>setPu = sd.getStudy().getPublicationss();
             System.out.println("@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@ In the query, size of the Publications List "+setPu.size());
                setPu.stream().forEach(sp-> {
                    tempListTitles.add(sp.getTitle());
                    tempListIdMed.add(sp.getPubMedId());
                });
                Set<Treatment>setTr = sd.getTreatments();
                /*setTr.stream().forEach(sp-> {
                    tempListTreatments.add(sp.getTreatmentName());
             });*/
             temp.setListPubObject(setPu);
             temp.setListTreatObject(setTr);
             siteDataViewDTOList.add(temp);
        });

        return siteDataViewDTOList;
    }

    private TypedQuery<SiteData> buildQuery(List<Filter> listFilters){
        CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
        CriteriaQuery<SiteData> cq = cb.createQuery(SiteData.class);
        Root<SiteData> siteData = cq.from(SiteData.class);
        Join<SiteData, Category> cat = siteData.join("category", JoinType.LEFT);
        Join<SiteData, Location> loc = siteData.join("location",JoinType.LEFT);
        Join<SiteData, Treatment> tre = siteData.join("treatments",JoinType.LEFT);
        Join<SiteData, Study> stu = siteData.join("study",JoinType.LEFT);
        Join<Study, Publication> pub = stu.join("publications",JoinType.LEFT);

        List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<>();
        int index = 0;

        for(Filter filter : listFilters){
            if("country".equals(filter.getName()))
                predicates.add(cb.equal(loc.get("country"), cb.parameter(String.class, filter.getName())));
            else if("category".equals(filter.getName()))
                predicates.add(cb.equal(cat.get("name"), cb.parameter(String.class, filter.getName())));
            else if("studyRef".equals(filter.getName()))
                predicates.add(cb.equal(stu.get("ref"), cb.parameter(String.class, filter.getName())));
            else if("studyType".equals(filter.getName()))
                predicates.add(cb.equal(stu.get("studyType"), cb.parameter(String.class, filter.getName())));
            else if("pubMedId".equals(filter.getName()))
                predicates.add(cb.equal(pub.get("pubMedId"), cb.parameter(Integer.class, filter.getName())));
            index++;
        }
        cq.where(cb.and(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[0])));

        return em.createQuery(cq);
    }
}
```

So, if anyone could throw some light on to this, it would be very helpful!

I Edit to add the main exception it throws:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: publications of: org.wwarn.vivax.manager.domain.Study
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractPropertyMapping.propertyException(AbstractPropertyMapping.java:83)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractPropertyMapping.toType(AbstractPropertyMapping.java:77)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.toType(AbstractEntityPersister.java:1978)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.FromElementType.getPropertyType(FromElementType.java:367)
```

Comment: Since you're heading Criteria API, consider using it's metamodel instead of plain strings for properties querying. Criteria API barely makes sense without metamodel and it can be replaced with JPQL with no particular loss.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a typo in your entity definition: "publicationss" instead of "publications". Since Hibernate uses JavaBeans properties for data access, it complains about getPublications() loss in your definition.

Metamodel preserves you from such typos, consider using it.

Comment: Hi, thank you for you reply, I have finally been able to figure out where the issue was, it was giving me lazy inizialization because I didn't have a fetch in the query, all I needed was: siteData.fetch("study").fetch("publications"); at the end of the QueryBuilder

  The getPublicationss is how it comes when I create the entities, don't ask me why>

Comment: By the way, I will consider using metamodel from now on ;)